# maximum execution time for long process in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Maximum HTTP Request execution time is 120sec in Node.js , how can i increase max execution time on http get/post requests?

NOTE:I'm using expressjs framework

Comment: No , i'm making requests about 8.000 to a API , because of that it is takes too much time.Moreover,  socket.io can solve this problem  but i want to do that with http get method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_timeout

> ## server.timeout
>
> Number Default = 120000 (2 minutes)
>   The number of milliseconds of inactivity before a socket is presumed to have timed out.
>
> Note that the socket timeout logic is set up on connection, so changing this value only affects new connections to the server, not any existing connections.
>
> Set to 0 to disable any kind of automatic timeout behavior on incoming connections.

Answer (score 2):

You would use `server.setTimeout(0);` to get what you're after. It's documented [here](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_server_settimeout_msecs_callback). Although I can't figure out why you would need to change this except for troubleshooting.